# How can I get the score from Question-Answer Pipeline? Is there a bug when Question-answer pipeline is used?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

When I run the following code

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad")
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad")

text = r"""
As checked Dis is not yet on boarded to ARB portal, hence we cannot upload the invoices in portal
"""

questions = [
    "Dis asked if it is possible to post the two invoice in ARB.I have not access so I wanted to check if you would be able to do it.",
]

for question in questions:
    inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(question, text, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors="pt")
    input_ids = inputs["input_ids"].tolist()[0]

    text_tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids)
    answer_start_scores, answer_end_scores = model(**inputs)

    answer_start = torch.argmax(
        answer_start_scores
    )  # Get the most likely beginning of answer with the argmax of the score
    answer_end = torch.argmax(answer_end_scores) + 1  # Get the most likely end of answer with the argmax of the score

    answer = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids[answer_start:answer_end]))

    print(f"Question: {question}")
    print(f"Answer: {answer}\n")
```

The answer that I get here is:

```
Question: Dis asked if it is possible to post the two invoice in ARB.I have not access so I wanted to check if you would be able to do it.
Answer: dis is not yet on boarded to ARB portal
```

**How do I get a score for this answer? Score here is very similar to what is I get when I run Question-Answer pipeline .**

I have to take this approach since Question-Answer pipeline when used is giving me Key Error for the below code

```
from transformers import pipeline

nlp = pipeline("question-answering")

context = r"""
As checked Dis is not yet on boarded to ARB portal, hence we cannot upload the invoices in portal.
"""

print(nlp(question="Dis asked if it is possible to post the two invoice in ARB?", context=context))
```

Comment: The score is calculated within the [_decode](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/b6512d235792f7be4effcb480f701944b051274b/src/transformers/pipelines.py#L1728) method. Regarding your keyerror, it is just telling you that it couldn't find a useful answer within your short context.

Comment: Thank you Cronoik. Really appreciated. However, both the codes are supposed to do the same thing I guess. So why the question-answering pipeline is failing whereas the first one is giving me an output?

Comment: Hi Cronik, can you please also show me how to use the decode method? I have gone through the link you provided, however unable to understand how to make use of it here in my context. I look forward to your valuable suggestions.

Comment: The codes will produce the same when they do actually the same thing. Currently the pipeline loads `DistilBertForQuestionAnswering` and not `bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad`. You can chance that by specifying the model parameter: `nlp = pipeline("question-answering", model='bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad')`. Which also produces an output for your example. You also have to keep in mind that the pipeline is more sopisticated as your code and covers more cases in the pre- and postprocessing. Therefore there will still be examples which will produce 1/2

Comment: different outputs. Regarding the _decode method, currently I don't have the time to explain you what happens there. If you can wait, I will come back to your question in two weeks. If not, feel free to submit an answer by yourself 2/2

Comment: Hi Cronoik, I really appreciate your time and thank you for your reply. I will definitely wait to hear back from you.

Comment: There is so much going on https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/b6512d235792f7be4effcb480f701944b051274b/src/transformers/pipelines.py#L1728 from Line 1679, 1716. I am looking into it :)

Comment: @Saumyadip: Sorry I completely forgot that I wanted to answer your question. I just remembered it today while answering a similar question. In case you are still interested, you can have a look at it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69516821/6664872).

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt to get the score. It appears that I cannot figure out what `feature.p_mask`. So I could not remove the non-context indexes that contribute to the softmax at the moment.

```py
# ... assuming imports and question and context

model_name="deepset/roberta-base-squad2"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_name)

inputs = tokenizer(question, context, 
                       add_special_tokens=True, 
                       return_tensors='pt')
input_ids = inputs['input_ids'].tolist()[0]

outputs = model(**inputs)
    

# used to compute score
start = outputs.start_logits.detach().numpy()
end = outputs.end_logits.detach().numpy()

# from source code

# Ensure padded tokens & question tokens cannot belong to the set of candidate answers.
#?? undesired_tokens = np.abs(np.array(feature.p_mask) - 1) & feature.attention_mask

# Generate mask

undesired_tokens = inputs['attention_mask']
undesired_tokens_mask = undesired_tokens == 0.0

# Make sure non-context indexes in the tensor cannot contribute to the softmax
start_ = np.where(undesired_tokens_mask, -10000.0, start)
end_ = np.where(undesired_tokens_mask, -10000.0, end)

# Normalize logits and spans to retrieve the answer
start_ = np.exp(start_ - np.log(np.sum(np.exp(start_), axis=-1, keepdims=True)))
end_ = np.exp(end_ - np.log(np.sum(np.exp(end_), axis=-1, keepdims=True)))

# Compute the score of each tuple(start, end) to be the real answer
outer = np.matmul(np.expand_dims(start_, -1), np.expand_dims(end_, 1))

# Remove candidate with end < start and end - start > max_answer_len
max_answer_len = 15
candidates = np.tril(np.triu(outer), max_answer_len - 1)
scores_flat = candidates.flatten()

idx_sort = [np.argmax(scores_flat)]
start, end = np.unravel_index(idx_sort, candidates.shape)[1:]
end += 1
score = candidates[0, start, end-1]
start, end, score = start.item(), end.item(), score.item()


print(tokenizer.decode(input_ids[start:end]))
print(score)
```

See more [source code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/b6512d235792f7be4effcb480f701944b051274b/src/transformers/pipelines.py#L1728)

Comment: Hey prayson, nice implementation. Is it possible to get the score if you use the default return type (list) instead of 'pt' . (As list is faster). Thanks!