# huggingface transformer question answer confidence score

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

How can we fetch the answer confidence score from the sample code of huggingface transformer question answer? I see that pipeline does return the score, but can the below core also return the confidence score.

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, TFAutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import tensorflow as tf

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad")
model = TFAutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad")

text = r"""
 Transformers (formerly known as pytorch-transformers and pytorch-pretrained-bert) provides general-purpose
architectures (BERT, GPT-2, RoBERTa, XLM, DistilBert, XLNet…) for Natural Language Understanding (NLU) and Natural
Language Generation (NLG) with over 32+ pretrained models in 100+ languages and deep interoperability between
TensorFlow 2.0 and PyTorch.
"""

questions = [
    "How many pretrained models are available in Transformers?",
    "What does Transformers provide?",
    "Transformers provides interoperability between which frameworks?",
]

for question in questions:
    inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(question, text, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors="tf")
    input_ids = inputs["input_ids"].numpy()[0]

    text_tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids)
    answer_start_scores, answer_end_scores = model(inputs)

    answer_start = tf.argmax(
        answer_start_scores, axis=1
    ).numpy()[0]  # Get the most likely beginning of answer with the argmax of the score
    answer_end = (
        tf.argmax(answer_end_scores, axis=1) + 1
    ).numpy()[0]  # Get the most likely end of answer with the argmax of the score
    answer = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids[answer_start:answer_end]))

    print(f"Question: {question}")
    print(f"Answer: {answer}\n")
```

Code picked up from
https://huggingface.co/transformers/usage.html

Answer (score 5):

The score is just a multiplication of the logits of the answer start token answer end token after applying the softmax function. Please have a look at the example below:
Pipeline output:

```py
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, pipeline

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad")
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad")

text = r"""
 Transformers (formerly known as pytorch-transformers and pytorch-pretrained-bert) provides general-purpose
architectures (BERT, GPT-2, RoBERTa, XLM, DistilBert, XLNet…) for Natural Language Understanding (NLU) and Natural
Language Generation (NLG) with over 32+ pretrained models in 100+ languages and deep interoperability between
TensorFlow 2.0 and PyTorch.
"""

question = "How many pretrained models are available in Transformers?"

question_answerer = pipeline("question-answering", model = model, tokenizer= tokenizer)

print(question_answerer(question=question, context = text))
```

Output:

```py
{'score': 0.5254509449005127, 'start': 256, 'end': 264, 'answer': 'over 32+'}
```

Without pipeline:

```py
inputs = tokenizer(question, text, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(**inputs)
```

At first, we create a mask that has a 1 for every context token and 0 otherwise (question tokens and special tokens. We use the [batchencoding.sequence_ids](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.BatchEncoding.sequence_ids) method for that:

```py
non_answer_tokens = [x if x in [0,1] else 0 for x in inputs.sequence_ids()]
non_answer_tokens = torch.tensor(non_answer_tokens, dtype=torch.bool)
non_answer_tokens
```

Output:

```
tensor([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True, False])
```

We use this mask to set the logits of the special tokens and the questions tokens to negative infinite and apply the softmax afterward (the negative infinite prevents these tokens from influencing the softmax result):

```py
from torch.nn.functional import softmax

potential_start = torch.where(non_answer_tokens, outputs.start_logits, torch.tensor(float('-inf'),dtype=torch.float))
potential_end = torch.where(non_answer_tokens, outputs.end_logits, torch.tensor(float('-inf'),dtype=torch.float))

potential_start = softmax(potential_start, dim = 1)
potential_end = softmax(potential_end, dim = 1)
potential_start
```

Output:

```
tensor([[0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,
         0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,
         0.0000e+00, 1.0567e-04, 9.7031e-05, 1.9445e-06, 1.5849e-06, 1.2075e-07,
         3.1704e-08, 4.7796e-06, 1.8712e-07, 6.2977e-08, 1.5481e-07, 8.0004e-08,
         3.7896e-07, 1.6438e-07, 9.7762e-08, 1.0898e-05, 1.6518e-07, 5.6349e-08,
         2.4848e-07, 2.1459e-07, 1.3785e-06, 1.0386e-07, 1.8803e-07, 8.1887e-08,
         4.1088e-07, 1.5618e-07, 2.5624e-06, 1.8526e-06, 2.6710e-06, 6.8466e-08,
         1.7953e-07, 3.6242e-07, 2.2788e-07, 2.3384e-06, 1.2147e-05, 1.6065e-07,
         3.3257e-07, 2.6021e-07, 2.8140e-06, 1.3698e-07, 1.1066e-07, 2.8436e-06,
         1.2171e-07, 9.9341e-07, 1.1684e-07, 6.8935e-08, 5.6335e-08, 1.3314e-07,
         1.3038e-07, 7.9560e-07, 1.0671e-07, 9.1864e-08, 5.6394e-07, 3.0210e-08,
         7.2176e-08, 5.4452e-08, 1.2873e-07, 9.2636e-08, 9.6012e-07, 7.8008e-08,
         1.3124e-07, 1.3680e-06, 8.8716e-07, 8.6627e-07, 6.4750e-06, 2.5951e-07,
         6.1648e-07, 8.7724e-07, 1.0796e-05, 2.6633e-07, 5.4644e-07, 1.7553e-07,
         1.6015e-05, 5.0054e-07, 8.2263e-07, 2.6336e-06, 2.0743e-05, 4.0008e-07,
         1.9330e-06, 2.0312e-04, 6.0256e-01, 3.9638e-01, 3.1568e-04, 2.2009e-05,
         1.2485e-06, 2.4744e-06, 1.0092e-05, 3.1047e-06, 1.3597e-04, 1.5105e-06,
         1.4960e-06, 8.1164e-08, 1.6534e-06, 4.6181e-07, 8.7354e-08, 2.2356e-07,
         9.1145e-07, 8.8194e-06, 4.4202e-07, 1.9238e-07, 2.8077e-07, 1.4117e-05,
         2.0613e-07, 1.2676e-06, 8.1317e-08, 2.2337e-06, 1.2399e-07, 6.1745e-08,
         3.4725e-08, 2.7878e-07, 4.1457e-07, 0.0000e+00]],
       grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward>)
```

These probabilities can now be used to extract the start and end token of the answer and to calculate the answer score:

```py
answer_start = torch.argmax(potential_start)
answer_end = torch.argmax(potential_end)
answer = tokenizer.decode(inputs.input_ids.squeeze()[answer_start:answer_end+1])

print(potential_start.squeeze()[answer_start])
print(potential_end.squeeze()[answer_end])
print(potential_start.squeeze()[answer_start] *potential_end.squeeze()[answer_end])
print(answer)
```

Output:

```py
tensor(0.6026, grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
tensor(0.8720, grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
tensor(0.5255, grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
over 32 +
```

P.S.: Please keep in mind that this answer does not cover any special cases (end token before start token).

Comment: @croinoik, thanks for the useful code.  You are right that there are cases not covered here, which are addressed in the pipeline.  Also, e.g., if you paste 500 tokens of nonsense before the context, the pipeline may find the right answer, but this technique may fail.  There are other factors like the pipeline having dropout, etc.  If so, do you know how one can access the actual mid-pipeline inputs, such as the softmaxes of the potential_start and end?  This is just one example, really I'd like to do this for any pipeline.

Comment: I think the following change brings the scores closer to that predicted by the pipeline.  Basically, find answer_start, then set all values to Inf in potential_end that appear after that index, since they are impossible.  You now have P(end=j|start=i), so that P(end=j & start=i) is the product of the conditional probabilities.
`non_answer_tokens2 = torch.tensor([xx if ii > answer_start else 0 for ii, xx in enumerate(non_answer_tokens.tolist())], dtype=torch.bool)`
`potential_end = torch.where(non_answer_tokens2, outputs.end_logits, torch.tensor(float('-inf'),dtype=torch.float))`

Comment: https://huggingface.co/course/chapter6/3b shows code to do this (though if you change the question it no longer works exactly, so apparently it is not exactly what is happening).  They show that instead of taking the argmax independently, only the softmaxes after each chosen start index should be considered.  In this case, the overall best will not always be the two argmaxes chosen independently, but rather the argmax after the product is performed from all possible valid pairs.  Note, for some reason, they do not normalize the second argmax vector (divide by the sum) to make it a probability.

Comment: @SamA. Sorry, I haven't found the time to reply to all your comments. Will do it over the weekend. But I think some of it already exceeds what should be discussed under an answered question. Maybe create a separate question to address your points.